# Iterate over three arrays simultaneously in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I want to iterate over 3 arrays should get an output as below, can someone help ?

```
~ cat new.csv
team1,team2,team3
CPMSCF,cpmscf,pipelineoperator
CPOCNCF,cpocncf,pipelineoperator

team1="$(cat new.csv | cut -d, -f1 | tail -n +2)"
team2=$(cat new.csv | cut -d, -f2 | tail -n +2)
team3=$(cat new.csv | cut -d, -f3 | tail -n +2)
```

```
for index in ${!team1[*]}; do
    echo "${team1[$index]}:${team2[$index]}:${team3[$index]}"
done
```

Output what I am getting is :

```
CPMSCF
CPOCNCF:cpmscf
cpocncf:pipelineoperator
pipelineoperator
```

but it should be

```
CPMSCF:cpmscf:pipelineoperator
CPOCNCF:cpocncf:pipelineoperator
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me as running your script gives the same expected output as you want.

Comment: sorry, mymistake. I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 1d file | while IFS="," read team1 team2 team3; do echo "$team1:$team2:$team3"; done
```

Output:

```
CPMSCF:cpmscf:pipelineoperator
CPOCNCF:cpocncf:pipelineoperator
```